# Merging two objects to a single one

Tags: java, java-stream

I am stuck on understanding how to merge two objects together, would appreciate explanation

The goal is to prevent situation when one of the properties located on another page while parsing information from one , so i am generating method that collects to map (key (invoice number) and value would be fully contracted object

```
public BenettonGroupPackingList combinePackingLists(BenettonGroupPackingList one, BenettonGroupPackingList two) {

}



public Map<String, BenettonGroupPackingList> groupByPackingListInvoiceNumber() {

    return groupPackingLists().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(BenettonGroupPackingList::getNumeroInternoNumber,
                    list -> list, this::combinePackingLists));
}
```

> public class BenettonGroupPackingList {

```
private String netWeight;
private String grossWeight;
private String numeroInternoNumber;
```

Comment: *how to merge two objects together*, depends on what attributes it holds and what the expectation is while merging them.

Comment: Are you using a util.List?

Comment: It would be helpfull to know a little more about ``BenettonGroupPackingList``

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: the names of your classes are a bit misleading and the code appears to be incomplete. Furthermore, there are multiple ways to combine objects and in these cases an example of input and desired output goes a long way explaining the problem. The above is making it very difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve so I'll answer to the best of my abilities but be aware there will be some work for you to do.

---

Assuming there are lists (which would justify the `java-stream` tag in the post) involved and all you do is to obtain a concatenated list, you could proceed as follows:

```
List combined_list = Stream.of(list_a, list_b).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above wouldn't remove any duplicate and would therefore merely be the concatenation of two collections.

---

Your classes however do not appear to be lists so combining them is a whole different story.
As it currently stands, it would appear as if you want to merge the corresponding property for each of your objects while at the same time ensuring that they are grouped by `numeroInternoNumber`. Such operation is much more complex and devising the algorithm is essentially your job so... I'll limit myself to broadly giving you steps to follow:

1. group the orders together by `numeroInternoNumber`. You can use a `groupingBy` collector (examples here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector). This should give you an object like `Map<String, List<BenettonGroupPackingList>>` to work on in subsequent steps
2. for each group, iterate on the objects within the group inspecting the `netWeight` and `grossWeight` properties, selecting the desired ones (probably the ones not null), saving the output in new `BenettonGroupPackingList` objects (example: `groups.entrySet().stream().map(e -> new BenettonGroupPackingList(e.getKey(), e.getValue().stream().anyMatch(x -> x.getNetWeight() != null ), e.getValue().stream.anyMatch(...)))`)
3. output the resulting collection of `BenettonGroupPackingList` objects